# kivy: have tcp event open popup

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I'm new to kivy, so apologies if I've missed something really basic here but I am struggling to understand both the behavior I'm getting as well as my inability to get the outcome I'm after.

#### The goal

The kivy app should be listening for TCP events from an external server, with certain triggers causing various stuffs in the kivy app. In this case, I want the external server to be able to open a popup in the app.

#### Illustrative Code

I have adopted the following (working) demo code from another SO answer that I can no longer seem to find, so apologies for the plagiarism but it is not intentional.

**server.py**

```py
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket()

host = 'localhost'
port = 54545

serversocket.bind(('', port))
serversocket.listen(1)
clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()

print("got a connection from %s" % str(addr))

while True:
    msg = input("> ")
    clientsocket.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
```

**client.py**

```py
import socket

class MySocket:
    def __init__(self,host="localhost",port=54545):
        self.sock = socket.socket()
        self.sock.connect((host, port))

    def get_data(self):
        return self.sock.recv(1024)
```

**main.py**

```py
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from threading import Thread

from client import *

kivy.require('1.9.1')


class MyEventDispatcher(EventDispatcher):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_test')
        super(MyEventDispatcher, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def do_something(self, value):
        self.dispatch('on_test', value)

    def on_test(self, *args):
        print('I am dispatched', args)
        CustomPopup().open()

class CustomPopup(Popup):
    pass

class MainScreen(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.sock = MySocket()
        Thread(target=self.get_data).start()

    def get_data(self):
        while True:
            self.text = self.sock.get_data().decode('utf-8').strip()

            if self.text == 'click':
                MyEventDispatcher().do_something(self.text)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

**my.kv**

```py
<MainScreen>:
    Button:
        text: 'I do nothing'

<CustomPopup>:
    title: 'Popup window'
    size_hint: .5, .5
    auto_dismiss: False

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            size_hint: .9, .9
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'
            text: 'message text goes here'
            text_size: self.width, None

        Button:
            text: 'A: Close'
            on_release: root.dismiss()

        Button:
            text: 'B: Close'
            on_release: root.dismiss()
```

This all works in that I can send the trigger word `click` from the server and the popup will open, it has multiple placeholder buttons that work. Hooray.

The problem, however, is that I seem to require the dummy button on the main app screen, which I do not want. If I simply eliminate the `<MainScreen>` bit from the `.kv` file, sending the `click` keyword leads to:

```
I am dispatched ('click',)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

but I can send any other string and it will display on screen as expected.

So, the basic questions are:

1. How do I get this to work as desired and
2. Why does placing a non-functional button on the screen make the popup work?

Thanks!